# remove item from listview xamarin when clicking in an item in the picker

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker, rest

in my listview i have a column contain a picker where i click to "delete" .when i click there, the elemnt has deleted in the database but i cant remove the item from the list in the same time "the operation was cancelled".
by the way i m consuming the http service rest api to delete.

xaml

```
   <ListView x:Name="viewRapport" ItemsSource="{Binding Rapports}" SeparatorVisibility="None" SelectionMode="None" ItemTapped="viewRapport_ItemTapped">
       <ListView x:Name="viewRapport" ItemsSource="{Binding Rapports}" SeparatorVisibility="None" SelectionMode="None" ItemTapped="viewRapport_ItemTapped">
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <ViewCell>
                       <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                           <Frame  BorderColor="white" Padding="0">
                               <Grid>
                                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                       <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                       <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                                       <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                                       <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                                       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                   <Label Grid.Column="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                   <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Amount}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" IsVisible="{Binding is}" x:Name="q"/>
                                   <Label Grid.Column="2" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Text="{Binding AmountReimbursed}"/>
                                   <Label>
                                       id.Column="3" TextColor="Red" x:Name="status"  LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Text="{Binding Status}">
                                   </Label>
                                   <Picker Grid.Column="4" x:Name="ListRap"  Title="..."  SelectedIndexChanged="rapp_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                   <Picker.ItemsSource>
                                   <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                                       <x:String>Modifier</x:String>
                                       <x:String>Supprimer</x:String>
                                   </x:Array>
                               </Picker.ItemsSource>
                           </Picker>
                       </Grid>
                   </Frame>
                   <Grid>
                       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                           <RowDefinition/>
                       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <ColumnDefinition/>
                           <ColumnDefinition/>
                           <ColumnDefinition/>
                       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Details" FontSize="13" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"/>
                       <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Modifier" FontSize="13" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" Command="{Binding modifBinding}" Clicked="Modif_Clicked"/>
                       <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="Supprimer" FontSize="13" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" Clicked="SuppClicked"/>
                   </Grid>
               </StackLayout>
           </ViewCell>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

xaml.cs

```
  private void rapp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ListR = sender as Picker;
        var item = (listraps)ListR.BindingContext;
        var id = item.Id;
        var choix = ListR.Items[ListR.SelectedIndex];
        switch (choix)
        {
            case "Supprimer":
                {
                      var vm = BindingContext as RootModel;
                    var r = ListR.BindingContext as listraps;
                    vm.RemoveCommand.Execute(r);

                    deleteExpenserapport(id); }
                break;
            case "Modifier":
                DisplayAlert("ok", choix, "ok");
                break;
        }


 public async void deleteExpenserapport(int id)
    {
        listraps r = new listraps();
        r.Id = id;

        var url = "http://192.168.1.3:3000/api/adepApi/DeleteExpenseReport?expenseReportId=" + id;
        var uri = new Uri(url);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);


        if (response.StatusCode== System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted) { 

            await DisplayAlert("Successfully", "you data have been Deleted", "OK"); }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("problem ", "no delete ", "OK");
        }
    }
```

in the viewmodel:

```
    public class ResponseDataN
    {
        public RootModel Data;
    }
    public class RootModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        public List<listraps> listRapts { get; set; }
        public RootModel()
        {
            listRapts = new List<listraps> { new listraps() };

                   }
        public Command<listraps> RemoveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command<listraps>((raport) =>
                {
                    listRapts.Remove(raport);
                });
            }
        }
```

my model:

```
 public class listraps
{
    //public string Titre { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public  int? UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public int? Duration { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal? AmountReimbursed { get; set; }}
```

Comment: Two things that I see, 1) You have set `ItemsSource="{Binding Rapports}"`, but you are doing a `listRapts.Remove(raport);`, so you want to remove from Rapports instead 2) The listView should use an ObservableCollection instead of a List. Here's a good example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding

Comment: @Saamer , concerning the ObservableCollection , i cant do it because when i used it i should define the variables like this:  employees.Add(new Employee{ DisplayName="Rob Finnerty"}); but for me , i cant define anything like DisplayName because it s full from consuming service

Comment: You have to understand that the ListView almost does an automatic refresh of the list when the binded property changes it value. So in your case, you have to either bind with ItemsSource="{Binding listRapts}", or do a Rapports.Remove(raport);

Comment: your comment about ObservableCollection makes no sense.  You should be able to use an ObservableCollection in place of a List without any changes to the model.